# 404 error with Github Pages and Custom Domain

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, custom-domain

I'm having some issues with setting up a custom domain with Github pages for my vue project, the problem started when I wanted to add a custom domain beforehand everything was working in terms of build and deploying. Once I added the custom domain I was receiving 404 error codes in my console. I will provide screenshots of everything I am seeing on my end below, it would be greatly appreciated if anyone can help.

[DNS check successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmZl0.png)

[DNS settings on Iwantmyname.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axIx5.png)

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFxEz.png)

[Chrome Network View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Vrr.png)

I tried looking for the file in my github repo to see if the path matches and it does, I also tried waiting it out to let it update globally but still nothing has changed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)